# Handling view that overlays system windows in Android

Tags: java, android

I keep running into an issue where the user presses and holds the power button and the power option window displays, but part of it is hidden behind a `RelativeLayout`.  Currently I am setting the `RelativeLayout` using:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(overlay_width, overlay_height, overlay_left, overlay_top,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
```

I need this `view` to be in front of everything, but I do not want it to show up in front of the system windows such as, the notification pull down bar and the power down options window.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using type toast `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,` use  TYPE_PHONE or TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY

I use this code and its working :-

```
  wm = (WindowManager) 
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            (int)desired_width, (int)desired_height, LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,   // First one is width then is height
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Check if you are again changing the type somewhere down

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've tried adding these in previously.  They just do not show up anymore.